# How to divide a duration by a number? (JavaScript, Google Sheet)

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I want to divide a time / duration that is in a cell by a number (5). Unfortunately I can not change the formula, so the time / duration is displayed correctly. "07:30" should appear in the cell.

I hope someone can help me. Thanks a lot.

```js
function pushDailyWorkTime () {

  var timeStamp = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var weeklyWorkTime = timeStamp.getRange(2, 8).getValue();
  var getNumberFormat = timeStamp.getRange(2, 8).getNumberFormats();
  
  var workingDays = (weeklyWorkTime / 5);
  
  timeStamp.getRange(11, 4).setValue(workingDays).setNumberFormats(getNumberFormat);

}


function addNewWeek() {

  pushDailyWorkTime()
}
```

[### Google Sheet Picture ###](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BnxRm.png)

Comment: Please add more details to your question. nothing is clear right now.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way is probably to call the moment.js library

Where you just take the duration, divided by 5, and display it in format of "HH:MM"

```
//cast the value into a moment
workingDays = moment((weeklyWorkTime / 5))
//console log the moment as HH:MM formatted string
console.log(workingDays.format('HH:MM'))
```

Didn't test it as I didn't see the actual values, but it *should* work.

See the full moment.js docs here: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/

Including how to call the library under "getting started".